# Heroku Push failing Ruby Rails App error while loading shared libraries, file too short

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was trying to push a new version of my rails app to my Heroku account which sits on a Heroku-16 stack but suddenly it began failing with the following error:

```
[master 195f4f9] ...
 1 file changed, 6 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
Counting objects: 15, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Writing objects: 100% (15/15), 1.66 KiB | 1.66 MiB/s, done.
Total 15 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/vendor/ruby/heroku-16/bin/../lib/libruby.so.2.2: file too short
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to myherokuapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/myherokuapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myherokuapp.git'
```

I tried doing a bundle update, that did not solve anything. I also tried undoing recent changes to the code and that did not resolve the issue. Finally, I also checked Heroku status and there are no relevant incidents that they have reported. Any idea why this would be occurring?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. I upgraded my ruby version in my gemfile to 2.3.7, one of the stated versions that Heroku says it supports and that seemed to resolve the issue.